# How to convert word date string to date format

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert one of the string columns which has date values in it to be converted to date format in pyspark dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(["2019 DECEMBER 12","2019 JANUARY 5",
       "2019 MARCH 7"], "string").toDF("src_col")
```

The column should be converted to following format:

```
2019 DECEMBER 12 --> 12-12-2019,
2019 JANUARY 5 --> 05-01-2019,
2019 MARCH 7 --> 07-03-2019
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_date` spark udf to convert String to Date

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(["2019 DECEMBER 12", "2019 JANUARY 5", "2019 MARCH 7"], "string").toDF("src_col")
df.withColumn('date', F.date_format(F.to_date('src_col', "yyyy MMMMM dd"),'dd-MM-yyyy')).show()
```

which results

```
+----------------+----------+
|         src_col|      date|
+----------------+----------+
|2019 DECEMBER 12|12-12-2019|
|  2019 JANUARY 5|05-01-2019|
|    2019 MARCH 7|07-03-2019|
+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, easy and usefull !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spark SQL date format and conversion functions to explicitly convert a date column to the required format.

Below is a code using spark DataFrame using Scala:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dates = Seq("2019 DECEMBER 12","2019 JANUARY 5").toDF("dateDF")

val formatDates = dates.withColumn("dateDF",date_format(
      to_date(col("dateDF"),"yyyy MMMMM dd"),"dd-MM-yyyy")
)

formatDates.show(false)
```

Hope this helps :)